# UIImageView does not appear in custom UITableViewCell that is created dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to integrate [MSSlidingPanelController](https://github.com/SebastienMichoy/MSSlidingPanelController) And I faced with problem. I want to have custom `UITableViewCell` that will contain image and text label.
I have `TableViewItem` inherited from `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_OPENSANS_BOLD size:15];
        [self.imageView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corners"]]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(45.0f, 30.0f, 16.0f, 16.0f);
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70.0f, 40, 240.0f, 20);
}

+ (TableViewItem *) tableViewItemWithUncheckableName:(NSString *)name
                          withLeftsideImageFromUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    TableViewItem   *item;

    NSParameterAssert(name);

    item = [[TableViewItem alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:g_LMVCCellIdentifier];
    [[item textLabel] setText:name];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        if ( data != nil )
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
                [[item imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: data]];
            });
        }
    });

    return (item);
}
```

Here how I use it:

```
- (TableViewSection *) fillingSectionUserInfo
{
    TableViewItem *userInfoItem;
    TableViewSection *section;

    UserLogic * userLogic = [UserLogic instance];
    NSString * userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[userLogic currentUser] stringForKey:@"firstName"], [[userLogic currentUser]stringForKey:@"lastName"]];

    userInfoItem = [TableViewItem tableViewItemWithUncheckableName:userName
                                          withLeftsideImageFromUrl:[[userLogic currentUser] stringForKey:@"photo" ]];
    [userInfoItem setActionWhenSelected:^(void){
    }];
    section = [TableViewSection tableViewSectionWitName:nil
                                          selectionRule:SelectionRuleNone
                                               andItems:userInfoItem, nil];

    return section;
}
```

For each item I make `setNeedsLayout` in `tableViewSectionWitName:selectionRule:andItems:`

Comment: Please in order to have more information to help you, could you check the following: check if [UIImage imageNamed:@"corners"] exist, you could add an NSAssert statement. Check if [UIImage imageWithData: data] is not nil with a NSAssert statement. At the end, please could you tell me why are you doing this: NSLocalizedString(nil, nil)? The first parameter of this method is usually an string, not nil.

Comment: @BarbaraRodeker Both are not nil. About last one - in other calling of the same method I used named sections, and here probably I copy and paste one of them and made this strange thing. I corrected it.